# How do I get a "busy wheel" on Windows Mobile 6?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, progress-bar

Windows Mobile pops up a "busy wheel" - a rotating colour disk - when things are happening .  I can't find in the documentation how this is done - can someone point me in the right direction?

We have a situation where we need to prompt the user to say we're doing stuff for a while, but we don't know how long it will take. So we can't do a progress bar, hence the proposal to use this busy wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SetCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940016.aspx)/[LoadCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453410.aspx)/[ShowCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453730.aspx) APIs, like this:

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));

// my code

ShowCursor(FALSE);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using compactframework.

Spining wheel:

System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;

Return to normal:

System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;

Comment: Note the poster's tag is C++, so the managed Cursor class does him no good.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing here, but I'd imagine it is [CWaitCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7bzytb%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Basically, you just create one on the stack, it appears, and disapppears when it is destructed as it goes out of scope e.g.

```
void DoSomethingSlow()
{
  CWaitCursor cw;
.
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: This is true only if you're using MFC

Answer (score 0):

From: http://mobiledeveloper.wordpress.com/2006/07/05/wait-cursor/

Have a look at Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

```
try {
 Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
 //Do something time consuming…
}
finally {
 Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Comment: The poster is looking for a C++ solution, not a managed solution